# Best way to handle ajax call with port in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I can't find any better solution in Google.

I have an MVC application.
When I use Visual studio the URL is

http://localhost:12345/NewApp - This works

When I deploy this to my local webserver the URL is

http://win2k12/NewApp - This works

I have a port forward on my router to port 8878 to point to the win2k12 server. I have a domain name (e.g. http://mydomain.uk) which is set to point to my actual IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx address. so when I want to access my MVC app externally I use this url

http://mydomain.uk:8878/NewApp - this works but only for the first level. When I call an Action through ajax like this
[image]

From the image above, the `baseUrl` only returns http://mydomain.uk/NewApp (without the port) which cause an error. My current workaround is to hardcode the port which is not Ideal.

I used `baseUrl` because If I don't the Virtual Directory doesn't get recognize. I'm sure this is just a workaround and I'm just wondering if there is a proper way of doing it.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var baseUrl = '@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)@Url.Content("~/")';
    $("a").click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).attr("action") == "Edit") {
            $("#dlgCode").empty()
                .load(baseUrl + "/Codes/Edit?id=" + $(this).attr("code_id") + "&timestamp=" + new Date().getTime());
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#dlgCode").css("display", "");
                $("#dlgCode").dialog({
                    width: "25%",
                    maxWidth: "768px",
                    title: "Edit Code"
                });
            }, 1000);
        } else if ($(this).attr("action") == "Delete") {
            $("#dlgCode").empty()
                .load(baseUrl + "/Codes/Delete?id=" + $(this).attr("code_id") + "&timestamp=" + new Date().getTime());
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#dlgCode").css("display", "");
                $("#dlgCode").dialog({
                    width: "25%",
                    maxWidth: "768px",
                    title: "Delete Code"
                });
            }, 1000);
        } else if ($(this).attr("action") == "Add") {
            $("#dlgCode").empty()
           .load(baseUrl + "/Codes/Add?id=" + $(this).attr("group_id")  + "&timestamp=" + new Date().getTime());
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#dlgCode").css("display", "");
                $("#dlgCode").dialog({
                    width: "25%",
                    maxWidth: "768px",
                    title: "Add Code"
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
        else if ($(this).attr("action") == "Cancel") {
            $("#dlgCode").dialog('close');
        }
        //console.log($("#dlgCode").html());
        //alert($(this).attr("code_id"));
    });
});
```

UPDATE:

I tried outputting the port from the view and re-deploy and access it externally but the port that gets recognize was 80.

```
alert('@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port');
```

Comment: Please include code as text, not as an image of text. My IDE doesn't let me paste images and compile them.

Comment: Apologies Mike. I've updated the post. Thanks.

Comment: Just an idea: how about to create different web.config for your deployments and store domain names in appsettings. Create a configuration environments (e.g. debug for local and release-deploy for deployment) for the deployment. When VS deploys your project it will automatically transform a web.config.  [See more 
 here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28VS.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks @DolceVita, the problem is in my webserver it's listening to port 80. On my router, it listens to 8878 which points to the webserver's ip and port 80. So I'm not sure how to do that. the link you have provided doesn't seem to show anything related to this issue.